# Default instance name of SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-express

I don't have access to a SQL Server Express installation at the moment, but I know that the installer usually installs SQL Server Express with an instance name. What is the default instance name for SQL Server Express installations? I.e., how do you access such an installation by default? Is it localhost\SQLEXPRESS$ ? Is the same name used for both 2005 and 2008 servers?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

When installing SQL Express, you'll usually get a named instance called SQLExpress, which as others have said you can connect to with localhost\SQLExpress.

If you're looking to get a 'default' instance, which doesn't have a name, you can do that as well. If you put MSSQLServer as the name when installing, it will create a default instance which you can connect to by just specifying 'localhost'.

[See here for details... MSDN Instance Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143531(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: If using the installation wizard (at least in 2014), you just need to check the "Default Instance" radio button when you get to the Instance Configuration step which will automatically specify the name to be "MSSQLSERVER".

Comment: For those using SQL Server Express via Docker, the default db name is `master` (and username is `sa`).

Answer (score 16):

Should be `.\SQLExpress`  or `localhost\SQLExpress` no $ sign at the end

See also here http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

Answer (score 5):

You're right, it's `localhost\SQLEXPRESS` (just no `$`) and yes, it's the same for both 2005 and 2008 express versions.

Comment: "for both 2005 and 2008 express versions." and SQL Express 2014

Answer (score 3):

The default instance name after installing is,

Server name:

> .\SQLExpress

Authentication:

> Windows Authentication

Note: The period in the server Name field means your local machine. For remote machines, use the machine name instead of the period.

This video also helps you to
[Find your sql server name (instance) for Management Studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GRw80-rnKRs) .

Answer (score 2):

If you navigate to where you have installed SQLExpress, e.g.

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn
```

You can run **SQLLocalDB.exe** and get a list of the all instances installed on your machine.

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn>SqlLocalDB.exe info 
>   MSSQLLocalDB 
>   ProjectsV12 
>   v11.0

Then you can get further information on the instance.

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn>SqlLocalDB.exe 
>   info MSSQLLocalDB
>   Name:               MSSQLLocalDB  
>   Version:            13.0.1601.5 
>   Shared name: 
>   Owner:              Domain\User 
>   Auto-create:        Yes 
>   State:              Stopped 
>   Last start time:    22/09/2016 10:19:33 
>   Instance pipe name:

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question "What is the default instance name of SQL Server Express?"  Your answer gives a list of LocalDB instances, which is a very useful answer, but to a different question: "What LocalDB instances exist on a machine?"     LocalDB is included in the SQL Server Express product installation, but LocalDB instances and  SQL Server instances (Express or otherwise) are different beasts.

Answer (score 0):

in my case the right server name was the name of my computer. for example John-PC, or somth