# Unable to connect to SQL server 2008 R2 via Instance name?

Tags: sql-server, windows-8, sql-server-2008-r2

I don't understand :

I've installed sql server 2008 R2. the installation process asked me for the desired instance name  , so I wrote: `MSSQLSERVER`.

after the installation , running *Setup Discovery Report* does shows me the instance name :

[image]

I've also installed all the service packs.

Also , all the services are up :

[image]

Also , all the ports are open ( tcp:1433 + udp :1434)

[image]

[image]

Also , Named pipes are on : [image]

So ,  where is the problem ?

I'm unable  to connect via the instance name :
[image]

Also unable   with :

`user\MSSQLSERVER` where `user` is the computer name.

Also unable  with : `.\MSSQLSERVER`

**But** (weird) :

Those 4 **do** work : (when I try to connect to them)

- `user` ( "user" is my machine name)
- `(local)`
- `.`
- `localhost`

Question :

why I can't use my instance name to connect to my sql server ?

Related info :

After connecting via one of the 4 who work  , I run a helpful info :

[image]

p.s. to be honets , I also asked this question in dba's stack site. ( cause I didn't know to which it more related)

Comment: is it possible that the 2nd sql server has the same name ?

Comment: @Dani who said I have 2 ? ( you can see it in services.msc picture where you see only MSSQLSERVER which is the service which runs the instance)

Comment: enter the instance name thus: YOURPC\MSSQLSERVER   or I think there is a shorthand something like .\MSSQLSERVER

Comment: @John did you read my whole question ?  I did write it _Also unable with : .\MSSQLSERVER_   also unable with _user\MSSQLSERVER_

Comment: I thought there was another instance of sql 2008.

Comment: @Dani oh ok :-) it aint. :-)

Comment: Mssqlserver is the name used for the default instance rather than a named instance. [as here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3586284/73226)

Comment: @MartinSmith but why I can't connect to it ? ( i mean Why I cant use the instance name itself)

Comment: You can connect to it. You don't specify a name when connecting to the default instance.

Comment: @MartinSmith when you say _"you don't"_  --do you mean :  "you don't" or "you can't" ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir "you can't" use the instance name. Martin is correct. As written on the link he pointed, the third bullet point under the Named instance section  says "If you specify MSSQLServer for the instance name, a default instance will be created.". The default instance is only 'localhost' or '.' or 'username'.

Comment: you are using SQL Server authentication, have you tried windows authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to connect to default instance of SQL Server. And for that you don't connect to instance using instance name but rather server name.

So for example if your machine name is **DBServer** and you are using default instance **MSSQLSERVER**, then you can simply connect to that instance either by specifying server name **DBServer** or **(local)** or **.** (just a dot)

Comment: Can we change the Instance Name, from Local to SQLEXPRESS ?

Comment: It really depends on version and type of instance. But personally I think it is less error prone to just reinstall SQL Server with new instance name. I will suggest you to post new question if you want to discuss it :)