# Connecting Unity with SQL Server Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, unity-game-engine, connection

I had a issue connecting Unity 5.5.3 to my database made with SQL Express. The error showed in Exception was:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Server does not exist or connection refused. ---> Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsInternalException: Server does not exist or connection refused. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Address incompatible with protocol.

My code for connection is that:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


public class connectivity : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string connectionstring;


// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{

    Debug.Log("Connecting to database...");
    connectionstring = "Server=localhost;" + 
                        "Database=Teste;" +
                        "User ID=fernando;" +
                        "Password=fernando123;";



    SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);


    try
    {

        dbConnection.Open();
        Debug.Log("Connected to database.");
    }
    catch (SqlException _exception)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning(_exception.ToString());

    }


    //  conn.Close();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}
}
```

Does somebody knows why it can't recognize the Server? I already have add the connection with my server using Server Explorer Data Connections.

Comment: Do you have SQLExpress server started locally?

Comment: have you searched on net for connection strings in sql server before posting the question

Comment: SQLExpress is a named instance. localhost is not going to work. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586196/default-instance-name-of-sql-server-express

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default instance name of SQL Server Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586196/default-instance-name-of-sql-server-express)

Comment: Yes for both. I have been trying four different strings and started SQLExpress as administrator. And I am in that for three days.

Comment: Thank you Ricardo. I will try that.

Comment: @FernandoMello Important question: Before you continue, do you plan to release this program anywhere on the internet/app store?

Comment: @Programmer that one no. But after that one I have others and they will use Web Servers (AWS). If you have some tips I accept.

Comment: And a new problem appear: I put my ip and my machine refuse to establish a connection.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that you won't release that. Anyways, if you plan to do so, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39140295/3785314) is what you should be doing.

Comment: @Programmer this program is to be used in LAN, security is not a problem in that case and WWW/UnityWebRequest is not available.
But thank you for the advice.

Comment: Ok. No problem.